# How can I hide the file path in the terminal window in vs code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal

So there is this 3 lines of something which looks like the path to the file in the terminal of vs code.

[image]

Now this is something which looks kind of unclean and I don't want it basically.
Is there a way to remove it/ hide it?

Some solutions suggested me to set `Java>Debug>Settings:Console` to `internalConsole` but that doesn't seem to work, when I run the code the terminal doesn't even show up. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or there is some other way to hide this...

Comment: Not trivially; the Java plugin runs via the terminal, so the run command and all its artifacts are just going to be there.

Comment: in `.vscode/launch.json` setting configuration with `"console": "internalConsole"`

Answer (score 0):

No way to hide scripts in Integrated Terminal but we can set `"console": "externalTerminal"` in `launch.json`, then **Run without Debugging**, java code will be executed in external terminal and no scripts shown:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

under such realities it's better to just have it log to your Debug Console without the extra crap...

- "console": "internalConsole" (this really means DebugConsole tab)
- "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart" (this forces the DebugConsole tab to open upon launching )

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Java: Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        }
    ]
}
```

P.S
Or check this YT video where guy is dealing with same issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSZqn1VrzVc